# Dataframe transformation (preparation to sql export)

Tags: sql, r, dataframe, transformation

How to make such transformation as in the below image ? [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the gather function form the tidyr package:

```
library(tidyr)

client1 <- c(23, 12, NA)
client2 <- c(45, 34, 56)
df1 <- data.frame(client1, client2)
df2 <- gather(df1, key = "Clients", value = "Money", na.rm = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

this can be done with `reshape` **package** also.

```
library(reshape)
df<-data.frame(client1=c(23,12,NA),client2=c(45,34,56))
melt(df ,measure.vars = c("client1","client2"))%>%setNames(.,c("Clients","Money"))
```